# Looking for a good way to exit an Android app in cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I create an Android app through cordova and I need to exit the app. I am using `navigator.app.exitApp()` which only makes the app to run in the background. It doesn't really exit the app. Is there a way to exit the app from cordova application?

Comment: Android does not support that; try with any other app and you'll notice the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install

```
cordova plugin add cordova-force-app-close
```

Usage

```
MOForceAppClose.forceAppClose()
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it seems it works as same as `navigator.app.exitApp()`.

Comment: it is used to forcefully exit the app